# My laptop with Win8.1 randomly stops responding to keyboard or mouse input

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, mouse, thinkpad

Randomly my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad W700) with Win8.1 will stop responding to keyboard input or mouse clicks. A reboot will resolve the issue until it occurs again. So far I have not been able to establish anything that I'm doing that creates the issue. I have the latest Lenovo updates installed, the latest MS updates installed, I have run various virus scans (Kaspersky, Malwarebytes, Spybot) and nothing is found.

When it stops responding I press Alt+Ctrl+Del and in the bottom right corner of the screen I will select reboot (at this point the laptop responds to the mouse).

When I installed Win8.1 it followed a clean install of Win8.1, e.g. I had formatted the drive. The keyboard is the KB in the laptop and the mouse is Lenovo Bluetooth ThinkPad mouse. I have turned off the touchpad on the laptop.

Comment: Do you have any programs that may affect your mouse or have control over your keyboard(e.g. WhatPulse)?

Comment: 1. Anything in the Error Log?   2. Have you checked Device Manager to see if any device is not working?